# jsfiddle working once only

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

This is a link to my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apurva4689/UyqFc/). I have a dropdown navigation bar on hover effect.This effect works only once when I run the project.After that it does not work till I run it again.
Does it have to do anything with the "Frameworks and Extensions" option? I read a little about it [here](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html) but have not clearly understood the difference between them. 
 This is my js code

```
function mainmenu(){
$("#bav .inner ul ul").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
$("#bav .inner ul li").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display:"none"}).slideDown(400, 'backout');
    },function(){
    $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
                       mainmenu();
        });
```

I am selecting onLoad" option".
Could anyone tell me why are the effects seen only once after running the code?

Comment: It seems to work fine in my browser (Google Chrome 26.0).

Comment: What is '**backout**'? remove that and it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/UyqFc/16/

Answer (score 0):

not sure why are you using backout in `slideDown()` but this is breaking the codes..

```
$(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400); //<---removed backout here
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/UyqFc/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't alter `visibility` and `display`. Just use `hide()` and `show()`. And your `slideDown` arguments are invalid. See http://jsfiddle.net/UyqFc/19/

```
$("#bav .inner ul ul").hide(); // Opera Fix
$("#bav .inner ul li").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('ul:first').slideDown();
}, function () {
    $(this).find('ul:first').hide();
});
```